# How to convert from String to Date?

Tags: java, android

I am getting the date (which is varchar in database) from database. I want to use this String as a date. the String format is "yyyy-mm-dd". How will it be converted to actual date type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two suggested options:

- [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) if you're happy using the JDK classes.
- [`DateTimeFormatter`](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) if you're doing a lot of date/time work and thus want to use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net).

Personally I'm a big fan of Joda Time (and *not* a big fan of the JDK classes) but as you're running on Android, you may not like the size of Joda Time. (You could build your own cut-down version, admittedly.)

Comment: yeah Jon, i am working on Android. I have got it with SimpleDateFormat. Thank you.

Comment: @Kamal: Sorry, that should have been *as* you're running on Android. If you're doing a lot of date/time work I'd still suggest using Joda Time as a generally-better API...

Answer (score 1):

Use the SimpleDateFormat:

```
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(string);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) object and call the [`parse(String source)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/DateFormat.html#parse%28java.lang.String%29) method to convert it back to date. Your date format will be `yyyy-MM-dd`. Example:

```
String dateString = "2010-04-06";
Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(dateString);
```

Comment: Can we use ">" operator with converted dates.

Comment: No, use `compareTo(otherDate)` method instead. See the javadoc for `compareTo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Use this example

```
try {  String str_date="11-June-07";
 DateFormat formatter ; 
 Date date ; 
  formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MMM-yy");
  date = (Date)formatter.parse(str_date);  
 System.out.println("Date is " +date );
  } catch (ParseException e)
  {System.out.println("Exception :"+e);  }  

 }
```